# json-server dockerfile won't bulld

Tags: reactjs, docker

my json-server works fine when I run the command in my local env.

```
    "scripts": {
        "serve-json": "json-server --watch ./server/userContactsDb.json --port 4000"
    },
```

However, when I try to serve via Docker via docker compose I get module not found error. Any ideas why this may be? I am working with a react project.

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  database:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: database.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
```

```
FROM node:12.6

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . . 

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["json-server", "--watch", "./server/userContactsDb.json", "--port", "4000"]
```

```
Attaching to bulle-test-project-main-database-1
bulle-test-project-main-database-1  | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628
bulle-test-project-main-database-1  |     throw err;
bulle-test-project-main-database-1  |     ^
bulle-test-project-main-database-1  | 
bulle-test-project-main-database-1  | Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/json-server'
bulle-test-project-main-database-1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:15)
bulle-test-project-main-database-1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)
bulle-test-project-main-database-1  |     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:839:10)
```

Comment: Do you have `json-server` installed locally in your project (is it in package.json) or is it global? And is there a reason for using such an old version of Node (18 is LTS right now)?

Comment: json-server is installed locally. Ah yes, i have changed to a newer node version but still same problem.

Comment: Share your `package.json` file

Comment: What part do you need as it's too long to add to the comments/orig post.

Comment: Why are you mounting your directory inside the docker container? You are copying everything anyways. Try removing `- .:/app` from volumes and run it again